# Altera uma relação entre dois campos mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a minha tabela de eventos (`tbl_eventos`), onde estou a ir buscar o campo id_contacto da tabela contactos (`tbl_contactos`). Para ir criar esta ligação, usei o seguinte:

```
ALTER TABLE `tbl_eventos`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `tbl_eventos_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_contacto`) REFERENCES `tbl_contactos` (`id_contacto`);
```

O que acontece agora é que a minha tabela de contactos mudou de nome, ou seja passou de `tbl_contactos` para `tbl_contactos_cliente`. Como posso fazer esta alteração? O código em cima foi gerado pelo phpmyadmin.

Comment: Não pode simplesmente executar o drop e criar de novo não?

Comment: @PedroLorentz, não era isso que pretendia. Mas se não encontrar outra solução terá de ser. Obrigado na mesma.

Comment: Não vou colocar como resposta por enquanto então para instigar mais pessoas a virem aqui e darem outra alternativa.

Comment: Acredito que a solução do @PedroLorentz seja a mais adequada pois é simples, amplamente utilizada e segura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sei, pelos comentários, que não é o que queria exatamente, mas acho que a melhor solução é executar DROP e ADD manualmente.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_eventos DROP CONSTRAINT tbl_eventos_ibfk_3;

ALTER TABLE tbl_eventos ADD CONSTRAINT [NOME_CONSTRAINT] FOREIGN KEY (id_contacto) REFERENCES tbl_contactos_cliente (id_contacto);
```

(E colocaria FK_Eventos_Contactos de nome :] )

Comment: sim, vou optar por esta opção. Obrigado!